# Enable disable Rigidbody 2D when touch phase starts?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello im having a hard time trying to enable and disable the kinematic of a rigidbody 2d i have been doing some experiments but nothing seems to work out This is the code without my experiments on how to enable and disable

for the backgrounf im a doing a puzzle game 2d it uses the box collider 2d to match the pieces, i  have many piecesand i want them to fall off with gravity , touch them and drag them to their spot , for that purpose i added a rigid body and it works perfectly  for the falll , but i need it to be kinematic so i can drag it

```
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform El_carmenPlace;
    private Vector2 initialPosition;
    private float deltaX, deltaY;
    public static bool locked;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && !locked)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            Vector2 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);


            switch (touch.phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:

                    if (GetComponent<Collider2D>() == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))
                    {
                        deltaX = touchPos.x - transform.position.x;
                        deltaY = touchPos.y - transform.position.y;
                    }

                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Moved:

                    if (GetComponent<Collider2D>() == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))
                        transform.position = new Vector2(touchPos.x - deltaX, touchPos.y - deltaY);
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    initialPosition = transform.position;
                    if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - El_carmenPlace.position.x) <= 0.5f &&
                        Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - El_carmenPlace.position.y) <= 0.5f)
                    {

                        transform.position = new Vector2(El_carmenPlace.position.x, El_carmenPlace.position.y);
                        locked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        transform.position = new Vector2(initialPosition.x, initialPosition.y);


                    }

                    break;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

i have try the enable disable ragdoll , scripts that unity post , i created an empty object and tried to add the piece of the puzzle , but i cant? is using rigidbody 2d dunno if it coutns as a rigid body...

Comment: Is this not C#? It doesn't look like [UnityScript](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Basically i fixed the two major problems , now for the wiinning part im using  if (ALtzayanca.locked && Huamantla.locked && El_carmen.locked) ,  i want to use a tag or something so when everthing is locked , you win

```
[SerializeField]
private Transform HuamantlPlace;
private float deltaX, deltaY;
public static bool locked;


//use this for initialiozation
void Start()
{

}


private void Update()
{

    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && !locked)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector2 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
        switch (touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:


                if (GetComponent<Collider2D>() == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))
                {
                    gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
                    deltaX = touchPos.x - transform.position.x;
                    deltaY = touchPos.y - transform.position.y;


                }

                break;
            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                if (GetComponent<Collider2D>() == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))
                    transform.position = new Vector2(touchPos.x - deltaX, touchPos.y - deltaY);

                break;
            case TouchPhase.Ended:

                if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - HuamantlPlace.position.x) <= 0.5f &&
                    Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - HuamantlPlace.position.y) <= 0.5f)
                {
                    this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
                    transform.position = new Vector2(HuamantlPlace.position.x, HuamantlPlace.position.y);
                    this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionX | RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionY;

                    locked = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;

                }

                break;
        }

    }
}
```

}